# Qt creating widgets

Tags: c++, qt, api, graphics, libraries

I'm writing an application using Qt that will display various custom widgets which have yet to be created.

I have a book on order, however whilst I'm waiting for it to arrive I would like to learn and play around with it.  I've used the MetaGraphics library years ago to create dynamic graphical objects that use blit regions to show animated objects.

I've seen that Qt also supports object blitting, I'm looking for good tutorials that will help me get to grips with the Qt libraries, functions and features.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Qt Online Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/) ?
There is plenty of staff and also step-by-step tutorials available.
For custom widgets the keywords you need are: `Graphics View Framework`, ex. [lots of samples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-graphicsview.html)